# Can't find files with a .txt extension with logs in FlightRecords (using DJI MSDK)

Tags: android, logging, sdk, dji-sdk

Can't find files with a .txt extension in FlightRecords. I use my own app to record flights and DJI MSDK.

I work on the Android App that uses DJI Mobile SDK. I came across an issue that I can't find txt files with my flight data in FlightRecord. There are only files with an extension .dat. When I use apps such as DJI GO, all files with logs exist. However, it doesn’t work the same when I use my app and the MSDK. I also looked for an information in the documentation about saving such txt files, but I think I can't do anything to save the files with logs manually.

I'll be grateful for any information!

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution.

In order to solve the issue - make an actual flight (not simulation). Using the SDK for flight simulation will not generate a FlightRecord, so the folder will be empty.